# How to delete foreign key entries with OneToMany relationship using JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have a Book, Author and Category entities.

Book has a `@OneToOne` relationship to Author and Book also has a `@OneToMany` relationship to Category.

The Book entity looks like:

```
@Entity
public class Book {
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    @OneToOne(orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "book", optional = true)
    private Author author

    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    @OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "book", targetEntity = Category.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Category> categories = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

The Author entity looks like:

```
@Entity
public class Author {
    @OneToOne(optional = false)
    private Book book;
}
```

The Category entity looks like:

```
@Entity
public class Category {
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "book_id", nullable = false)
    private Book book;
}
```

I am having a problem with the JPA delete. In my test case I have two Category entries linked to one Book entry. I would expect the corresponding entries for Category and Author to also delete when I delete the Book entry.

The delete call in my service is:

```
bookRepository.delete(book);
```

However I find the only the Author entry is deleted and all other entries are still present. Can you spot something wrong in my set-up? I don't want to manually delete all foreign key entries before deleting the Book entry.

Comment: Try deleting in the book entity the orphanRemoval attribute or with orphanRemoval = false